# What actually happens between Star Wars Episode III and IV?

Tags: star-wars

I have read some books based between these two episodes and even played some games. But what actually happens between these two episodes, I understand the Rebel Alliance was born with the help of "Starkiller" if you accept that he was there, otherwise many believe it was just Senators Organa, Mon Morthma and Garm Bel Iblis. But what else happened. Did anyone else challenge the Emperor? or is it just a very boring story between them?

Some books point to Darth Vader having a secret apprentice, which I can see being "StarKiller" from Star Wars the Force Unleashed, but there is also a book about the Emperor having an old apprentice come back for revenge. Is there anything else interesting like this?

Comment: “is it just a very boring story between them?” *Attack of the Clones* was a very boring story, so it wouldn’t surprise me.

Comment: Jar Jar dies, thank god.  Also, the movies stop sucking.

Comment: @WadCheber His voice is heard at the end of episode 6. But I think it is safe to assume he died before the end of episode 7. At least according to one interview I heard it was considered to settle that matter by discretely placing his skeleton in one of the scenes in that movie, or have him be present on a planet about to be blown to pieces.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### New Disney Canon

<sub>*Preface*:For those not familiar, in April 2014 we saw major changes to Star Wars canon rules, resulting from Disney acquiring ownership of Lucasfilm.</sub>

<sub>* The changes were delineated in great detail in this wonderful blog post on SFF.SE blog by Richard (AKA Valorum): https://thesffblog.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/</sub>

<sub>* The short version is that virtually none of the pre-April '14 Star Wars works are considered Disney canon (they were all bundled into a new "Legends" canon <strike>so Disney can keep making money off gullible fans</strike>) except for 6 Lucas films and *Clone Wars* cartoons.</sub>

<sub>* However, 100% of works published by Disney-owned Lucasfilm are fully Disney canon</sub>

Disney canon is relatively new and - based on evidence so far - keeps growing at a steady rate including works covering events between Episodes III and IV

Therefore, this answer is by necessity incomplete. **In its current form it is accurate as of July 2015**; and virtually guaranteed to need to be updated in the future.

Please note that

1. a fairly complete chronology of **works** in New Disney Canon can be found on Wookieepedia here: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media;
2. a somewhat less complete chronology of events in New Disney Canon can be found on Wookieepedia here: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history/Canon#cite_note-Episode_IV-25

Some highlights of the main events (so far, a vast majority is concentrated around "*Star Wars: Rebels*" storyline, but some also in prequel books:

- **~16 BBY:** Emperor Palpatine and Vader confront Free Ryloth movement, as a result of which Cham Syndulla (Hera Syndulla's father) realizes that to win, they need to organize Galaxy-wide rebellion
- **~12 BBY:** Obi-Wan prohibited from visiting Lars homestead again by Owen.
- **~11 BBY:** Kanan Jarrus (former Jedi Padawan) joins forces with Hera Syndulla, starting what would become Lothal rebels
- **~5 BBY:** Ezra Bridger is recruited by the Lothal rebels. Kanan Jarrus decides to become a Jedi again
- **(unknown date):** Bail Organa and Ahsoka Tano organize a rebel network.
- **(unknown date):** Senator Bail Organa forms Alliance to Restore the Republic
- **(whole period):** Wilhuff Tarkin supervises the construction of Death Star, proposes the strategy of governance by Moffs and Grand Moffs to the Emperor, and becomes one of the latter.

---

### Pre-Disney (aka "Legends") Canon:

**For a list of significant events**, see: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history

Too much to list between 18BBY and Battle of Yavin, but some minor interesting events are:

- **10 BBY:** The Kamino Uprising.
- **8 BBY:** Emperor Palpatine discovers a method of transferring his consciousness into a new body in a Holocron retrieved from Jedi Master Ashka Boda.
- **7 BBY:** On Falleen, two hundred thousand Falleen perish in a controlled Imperial bombardment of a city ruled by Xizor's father to quarantine the spread of a biological weapon.
- **5 BBY:** Han Solo, now in a military academy, saves Chewbacca, now a slave, and is subsequently drummed out of the Imperial Navy. Chewbacca pledges a life-debt to Han Solo and remains his partner for the next three decades.
- **5 BBY:** Lando Calrissian wins the Millennium Falcon in a game of sabacc.
- **5 BBY:** Kyle Katarn enters the Imperial Academy of Carida.
- **4 BBY:** Jorj Car'das's starship is commandeered by a Bpfasshi Dark Jedi. The vessel crashes on Dagobah, where Yoda kills the Dark Jedi and heals Car'das.  (DVK NOTE: may not be canon anymore. Thank, bastard Lucas!)
- **2 BBY:**

  - Meant to eventually overthrow the Emperor, Darth Vader sends a secret apprentice, Starkiller, to hunt down and eradicate the last of the Jedi.
  - The apprentice, Galen Marek, under orders from Vader seeks out the opposers and secret enemies of the empire and convinces them to organize to actively fight the Emperor.
  - The apprentice, Galen Marek ultimately turns against both Vader and Palpatine and is killed.
  - Inspired by the death of Galen Marek, the Corellian Treaty is signed, giving birth to the Rebel Alliance.
  - The Galactic Civil War begins.
- 2 BBY: Han Solo wins the Millennium Falcon from Lando Calrissian during a sabacc tournament on Cloud City.
- 1 BBY: A group of Moffs led by Trachta, plot to overthrow Emperor Palpatine and Darth Vader. The plot fails and almost all of the conspirators are met with unspeakable deaths.

---

**Also, for a list of chronological works**: see https://web.archive.org/web/20150210072542/http://timelineuniverse.net:80/History.htm

You want to search for "*Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*" in month 36 ABG (After Battle of Geonosis) for the start of the period, and of course finish at 0 BBY (*Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope*).

---

As extra reading, please look at "[Star Wars Timeline Gold](http://www.starwarsfanworks.com/timeline/)", download latest (2011 edition) there. You want to read staring somewhere on page 506

Comment: good answer but I am not a fan of http://timelineuniverse.net/History.htm, but that is a website design issue not yours.

Comment: "Han Solo wins the Millennium Falcon from Lando Calrissian during a sabacc tournament on Cloud City" is in that list twice at two different dates. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen - copy/paste gone wild. Fixed. Thx

Comment: *Wilhuff* Tarkin? With a name like that, something tells me he was bullied a lot at school. No wonder he turned to evil.

Answer (score 2):

The events of *Star Wars: Rebels* are between III and IV

After purchasing Lucasfilm Disney said they no longer considered the expanded universe novels as canon. The only canon being the films, the Clone Wars cartoons and any comics published after the acquisition.

https://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page

As such the only canonical events between Ep III and Ep IV are those shown in Rebels, or the books and comics released post April 2014.

Comment: There are new official canon books covering this period as well. "Tarkin" and "A New Dawn" [Rebels prequel] for sure, "Lords of the Sith" does as well I think. I don't think any of the new comics do though.

Comment: This is absolutely not true - there's plenty of new canon outside just "Rebels". Sorry, -1.